# Why is this sentence containing "except" translated into this conjunction?

Tags: logic

```
All except students are invited
```

This proposition was translated into

```
No student is invited, and all non-students are invited
```

Why was it translated into this  conjunction of form A∧B

and not into one of its conjuncts A or B?

Comment: What is your proposed "A only" translation ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA all non students are invited

Comment: "all non students are invited" does not excluded that also students are invited.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but all non students are invited automatically let us to think that ok all students are not invited (excluded)

Comment: No, stating that the invitation includes all non-students does not *automatically* exclude any students.  You have to be explicit about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question, the reason is that **except** is not as "atomic" as it may sound. Except provides two pieces of information and not one. Therefore, it should be broken down to 2 propositions.

Let A mean `No student is invited` and B mean `all non-students are invited`

**Let us translate the proposition (with except) to A : `No student is invited`**

Well, if no student is invited, it does not say anything about non-students, while the original proposition with 'except' says that all are invited except students.

**Let us translate the proposition (with except) into B : `all non-students are invited`**

Now, does the proposition B say anything about students? it only states that all non-students are invited, while the original proposition states that students are not invited **(except students)**

That is why you have to add A and B as conjuncts.

**Edit**

There is no quantifier for "except" in predicate first-order logic, because it can be broken down to "All" and "Some" quantifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this similar example (assuming for simplicity that *man* and *woman* are the only two genders...) :

> All women are humans.

This is the same as : "All non-man are humans".

According to your proposal, this is the same as :

> All except men are humans.